# converting Splatted Array to Formatted HTML email in power shell without creating a file

Tags: html, powershell, active-directory

hi upon creation of a new user im wanting to take the $newuserParams, and put them in a nice formatted email. with each parameter on a new line.
ive got either the splatted params outputting all as one big line with | out-string, or i get this

```
IsReadOnly  IsFixedSize IsSynchronized  Keys    Values  SyncRoot    Count
False   False   False   System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection  System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection    System.Object   22
```

if i use ConvertTo-HTML

i basically want to do both but chaingin both pipes doesn't work haha, how do i make the array populate so that i can use the ConvertTo-HTML

i want to keep it part of the $mailbody.add, as i have other things adding to $mailbody.

```
$NewUserParams = @{
            SamAccountName    = $username
            Name              = "$firstname $surname"
            DisplayName       = "$firstname $surname"
            UserPrincipalName = "$username@cyclone.com"
            GivenName         = $firstname
            Surname           = $surname
            AccountPassword   = $securePassword
            Enabled           = $false
            Path              = "OU=$NewUserOU,$domainpath"  #change to switch based of Users Branch
            City              = $_.City
            Country           = $_.Country                  #NOTE: This Feild must be the 2 digit Country Code, NOT the String Name of athe Country.
            company           = $_.CompanyName
            department        = $_.OrgDepartmentName
            Employeeid        = $_.EmployeeId
            mobile            = $_.Mobile
            Manager           = $_.Manager
            Office            = $_.Branch
            postalCode        = $_.PostalCode
            POBox             = $_.PostOfficeBox
            scriptPath        = $_.scriptPath
            StreetAddress     = $_.StreetAddress
            Title             = $_.Title



        }

        try {
            #Create the NEw user, and make them change password on first Logon
            New-ADUser @NewUserParams -ErrorAction Stop
            Set-ADUser -Identity $username -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
           # $CurrentAttributes = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Properties *
            [void]$mailBody.add("<h1>NEW User Created</h1> $($newUserParams| ConvertTo-Html)")
            #Send-MailMessage @MailParams
            Write-Host "email sent to Admin"
        }
        catch {

            throw
            Write-Warning "Could not create account $username. $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
    if ($mailbody -ne @()) {

        Write-Host "Change Added to mail"
        "$(Get-Timestamp )USER Attribute Change $mailbody" | Out-File c:\log.txt -Append

        Send-MailMessage @MailParams -BodyAsHtml -body "<b>$(Get-TimeStamp): USER UPDATE </b> <p>$mailbody</p>"
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `$mailbody.add()` do?

Comment: Also in your code `$_` should be replaced with the object name you are using for those variables

Comment: the $_, is part of a for each user in the .csv file, and the $mailbody.add adds the text when there is a change to an array list($mailbody) that at the end is output as the contents of the email and appends to the log file where i call $mailbody at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick shortcut; since `$NewUserParams` is already a hash, cast it to a PSCustom object.

```
$NewObject = [PSCustomObject]$NewUserParams
```

At that point you've got all sorts of options including `ConvertTo-Html`.

Personally I like to pipe to `Format-List | OutString` Then just slap a `\<PRE>...\</PRE>` around it.  I like to use a mono-spaced font so the HTML will have the same table or list spacing just like you get in the PowerShell console.  I frequently do this with Format-Table as well.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the `ConvertTo-Html` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html?view=powershell-7) it has the following:

*Converts a .NET object into HTML that can be displayed in a Web browser.*

The reason behind this behavior is Hashtables have key and value pairs opposed to PSCustomObject which is properties, so `ConvertTo-Html` treats them differently and you get the behavior you are experiencing.

```
#$ADObject | ForEach-Object {
$NewUserParams = @{
            SamAccountName    = $username
            Name              = "$firstname $surname"
            DisplayName       = "$firstname $surname"
            UserPrincipalName = "$username@cyclone.com"
            GivenName         = $firstname
            Surname           = $surname
            AccountPassword   = $securePassword
            Enabled           = $false
            Path              = "OU=$NewUserOU,$domainpath"  #change to switch based of Users Branch
            City              = $_.City
            Country           = $_.Country                  #NOTE: This Field must be the 2 digit Country Code, NOT the String Name of athe Country.
            company           = $_.CompanyName
            department        = $_.OrgDepartmentName
            Employeeid        = $_.EmployeeId
            mobile            = $_.Mobile
            Manager           = $_.Manager
            Office            = $_.Branch
            postalCode        = $_.PostalCode
            POBox             = $_.PostOfficeBox
            scriptPath        = $_.scriptPath
            StreetAddress     = $_.StreetAddress
            Title             = $_.Title



        }

        try {
            #Create the Nww user, and make them change password on first Logon
            New-ADUser @NewUserParams -ErrorAction Stop
            [PSCustomObject]$NewUserParams = $NewUserParams
            Set-ADUser -Identity $username -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
           # $CurrentAttributes = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Properties *
            [void]$mailBody.add("<h1>NEW User Created</h1> $($newUserParams| ConvertTo-Html)")
            #Send-MailMessage @MailParams
            Write-Host "email sent to Admin"
        }
        catch {

            throw
            Write-Warning "Could not create account $username. $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
    if ($mailbody -ne @()) {

        Write-Host "Change Added to mail"
        "$(Get-Timestamp )USER Attribute Change $mailbody" | Out-File c:\log.txt -Append

        Send-MailMessage @MailParams -BodyAsHtml -body "<b>$(Get-TimeStamp): USER UPDATE </b> <p>$mailbody</p>"
    }
}
```

Successful output of generating HTML:
[image: Output]

Comment: I think you have to create the PSCustomObject after the hash is referenced by the `New-ADUser` command. I don't think splatting works with an object.